# Understanding the random function in Python coding

Tags: python, psychopy

I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand the random function in Python?

```
nLines=500
xys = random([nLines,2])*500-250 
oris = random(nLines)*180
```

In the example here, the values of the oris will be between 0-180. (based on what the website said)

How is this achieved by using `*180`? Does multiplying (*) indicate something for the random function?

And would the xys value be between 0 to 250?

Thank you.

Comment: The standard Python `random` function takes no inputs. Apparently `pschocopy` has its own (either that, or your code is buggy). Perhaps you could read its documentation. In any event, `*` is just ordinary multiplication here.

Answer (score 1):

The * is normal multiplication. random() funtcion takes no parameters so your code might give an error in compilation. The random() function returns a float between 0 and 0.999999 so multiplying it by 180 will give you a number between 0 and 179.999999. Finally, xys will not have a value between 0 and 250. It will have a value between -250 and 250.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand that now. 
Oddly enough the code runs fine on PsychoPy - but I am guessing the best way to represent this would be to use `random.random` as opposed to just `random`.
Thanks again